# How can ASTER elevation data be converted to a CAD model?

Tags: 3d, elevation, cad, aster

I am trying to convert ASTER elevation data to a 3D CAD model using only opensource software.  I have tried using different file formats but I have been unsuccessful.  I use QGIS for my GIS work and would like to open the model using something like Sketchup or Meshlab.